# How to obtain the target of a symbolic link (or Reparse Point) using .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, ntfs, symlink

In .NET, I think I can determine if a file is a symbolic link by calling System.IO.File.GetAttributes(), and checking for the ReparsePoint bit.  like so:

```
var a = System.IO.File.GetAttributes(fileName);
if ((a & FileAttributes.ReparsePoint) != 0)
{
    // it's a symlink
}
```

How can I obtain the target of the symbolic link, in this case?

---

ps: I know how to **create** a symbolic link. It requires P/Invoke:

```
[Interop.DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint="CreateSymbolicLinkW", CharSet=Interop.CharSet.Unicode)] 
public static extern int CreateSymbolicLink(string lpSymlinkFileName, string lpTargetFileName, int dwFlags);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use DeviceIoControl() and send the FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT control code.  The P/Invoke and API usage details are quite gritty, but it [Googles really well](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=c%23+FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT&aq=f&aqi=&oq=&fp=d95f0d161f018361).

Comment: This led me to the source code for the Powershell Community Extensions (PSCX), which has good code for handling ReparsePoints.

Answer (score 17):

Based on the answer that mentioned `GetFinalPathNameByHandle` here is the C# code that does this (since all other answers were just pointers):

Usage

```
var path = NativeMethods.GetFinalPathName(@"c:\link");
```

Code:

```
public static class NativeMethods
{
    private static readonly IntPtr INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = new IntPtr(-1);

    private const uint FILE_READ_EA = 0x0008;
    private const uint FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS = 0x2000000;

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern uint GetFinalPathNameByHandle(IntPtr hFile, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] StringBuilder lpszFilePath, uint cchFilePath, uint dwFlags);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateFile(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string filename,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint access,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileShare share,
            IntPtr securityAttributes, // optional SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES struct or IntPtr.Zero
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileMode creationDisposition,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint flagsAndAttributes,
            IntPtr templateFile);

    public static string GetFinalPathName(string path)
    {
        var h = CreateFile(path, 
            FILE_READ_EA, 
            FileShare.ReadWrite | FileShare.Delete, 
            IntPtr.Zero, 
            FileMode.Open, 
            FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
            IntPtr.Zero);
        if (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            throw new Win32Exception();

        try
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
            var res = GetFinalPathNameByHandle(h, sb, 1024, 0);
            if (res == 0)
                throw new Win32Exception();

            return sb.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseHandle(h);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think (but I have not tested) but you may be able to simplify your code using  a .NET FileStream object then using `var h = yourStream.SafeFileHandle.DangerousGetHandle()`, when you close the stream you also release the handle so you don't need to call `CloseHandle(h)` on that variable. You could even make the function take in a `FileStream` instead of a string.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - the reasons why I did not use FileStream is a) I am not sure if it would pass through the attributes that are not defined in .NET and b) I am not sure if it would work for directories as well (CreateFile does work). Plus this should be faster (though I did not measure it).

Comment: If you're like me, the next thing you'll want to know is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31439011/getfinalpathnamebyhandle-without-prepended

Comment: @datguy Are you aware that the paths prepended with `\\?\ ` are actually valid and usable? It also has some benefits (telling Windows to use the Unicode extensions where possible, bypassingthe `MAX_PATH_LENGTH` limit) By all means, strip it for aesthetic reasons, but it's a perfectly valid responsee

Comment: `GetFinalPathNameByHandle` can fail on a volume that did not register with the volume manager, this includes Passmark OSFMount.

Answer (score 13):

In .NET 6 you can use the property [LinkTarget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.linktarget?view=net-6.0)

```
bool IsLink(string path)
{
    var fi = new FileInfo(path);
    return fi.LinkTarget != null
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[Open the file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) using `CreateFile`, and then pass the handle to [GetFinalPathNameByHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364962(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: @Cheeso: symlinks to files debuted in Vista, AFAIK. So, all of the file based symlink functins will have that same restriction.

Comment: Reparse points have been around since Win2k; it's only symbolic links to files that debuted in Vista.

Comment: For some reason, I consistently get an Access Violation when calling this method... not sure why

Comment: Regarding Vista, anything is better.

Comment: 9 years later, the first link is broken.

Comment: @Grault - can't find (and don't remember) the Raymond Chen commentary, so updated link to the CreateFile function needed to open