# What happens when I DllImport a function that is not available on the runtime platform?

Tags: .net, windows, winapi, dllimport, ntfs

I previously asked, [How to determine the target of a symbolic link or Reparse Point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302416) 
...and got [an answer that suggested the use of the Win32 function GetFinalPathNameByHandle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302416/in-c-how-to-obtain-the-target-of-a-symbolic-link-or-reparse-point/2302485#2302485), a function first available on Vista.

What happens if I build the .NET Assembly and then attempt to run it on WinXP, or WS2003, which does not have the  [GetFinalPathNameByHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364962%28VS.85%29.aspx) function?   Is there a runtime exception, and if so, which one?  Is there a way for me to handle that case in the app code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll get an [`EntryPointNotFoundException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.entrypointnotfoundexception.aspx) when you call the method.

If the entire DLL file doesn't exist, you'll get a [`DllNotFoundException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dllnotfoundexception.aspx) instead.

Comment: And those exceptions are normal, catchable?

Comment: Yes. What makes you think they wouldn't be?

Comment: Using LoadLibrary, GetProcAddress, FreeLibrary can avoid the exception.  Not sure if that make sense if you can't support the functionality anyway.