# GetFinalPathNameByHandle() result without prepended '\\?\'

Tags: c++, winapi, file-management

Here is my code snippet:

```
char existingTarget[MAX_PATH]; 
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(linkPath.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hFile)
{
    GetFinalPathNameByHandle(hFile, existingTarget, MAX_PATH, FILE_NAME_OPENED);
    CloseHandle(hFile);
}
```

However, `existingTarget` is coming out to be `\\?\C:\mydir\etc`. How can I get it to return just `C:\mydir\etc`?

*Note*: I don't want to check for the string `\\?\` and just `memmove` it, it's a bit too hackish of a solution for this program.

Comment: Some targets may not be valid or representable without the prefix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> how can I get it to return just C:\mydir\etc

You cannot.  `VOLUME_NAME_DOS` and `VOLUME_NAME_GUID` *always* use that format, and is documented as such:

> The string that is returned by this function uses the `\\?\` syntax.

See the **example results** in the Community Additions section of the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364962.aspx).

> Note: I don't want to check for the string `\\?\` and just memmove it, its a bit too hackish of a solution for this program.

That is the easiest solution.  Otherwise, you have to use other APIs to translate the returned path into a more human-readable path.  Such as using the result of `VOLUME_NAME_NT` with [`QueryDosDevice()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365461.aspx), or using the result of `VOLUME_NAME_GUID` with [`GetVolumePathNamesForVolumeName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364998.aspx).

Comment: Do you know if the \\?\ is always prepended? Or does it vary from system to system?

Comment: I addressed that in my answer.

Comment: @amza: \\?\ is the prefix that changes `CreateFile` to point at the NT namespace rather than the NT namespace.

Comment: @BillyONeal that makes no sense. Read what you wrote.

Comment: I don't see how you can use ``QueryDosDevice`` since it only use the lpDeviceName (ex: "C:"), not the full VOLUME_NAME_NT. A code example would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I know, you don't want to check for `\\?\` and remove it, but as Remy explains in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31439235/2675154), that's the easiest solution. However, you should be careful, because local paths and network paths have different prefixes. As you know, a local path starts with `\\?\`, but a network path starts with `\\?\UNC\` (as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file)), for example:

```
\\?\UNC\My server\My share\Directory
```

As a result, based on your code, my solution to remove the prefixes is as follows:

```
char existingTarget[MAX_PATH];
HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA(linkPath.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hFile)
{
    DWORD ret = GetFinalPathNameByHandleA(hFile, existingTarget, MAX_PATH, FILE_NAME_OPENED);
    CloseHandle(hFile);

    // Check whether existingTarget is large enough to hold the final path.
    if (ret < MAX_PATH)
    {
        // The local path prefix is also a prefix of the network path prefix.
        // Therefore, look for the network path prefix first.
        // Please note that backslashes have to be escaped.
        std::string targetPath(existingTarget);
        if (targetPath.substr(0, 8).compare("\\\\?\\UNC\\") == 0)
        {
            // In case of a network path, replace `\\?\UNC\` with `\\`.
            targetPath = "\\" + targetPath.substr(7);
        }
        else if (targetPath.substr(0, 4).compare("\\\\?\\") == 0)
        {
            // In case of a local path, crop `\\?\`.
            targetPath = targetPath.substr(4);
        }
    }
}
```

If needed, you can still use `memmove()` to copy `targetPath` into another variable.

Answer (score -1):

There's a few other approaches if you don't want to do parsing stuff:

- `std::filesystem` can handle it (at least with MSVC, didn't check GCC on MinGW or Cygwin), if you don't mind having an `std::string`:

  ```
  #include <filesystem>
  #include <string>
  ...
  std::string cleanerPath = std::filesystem::canonical(existingTarget).string();
  // use weakly_canonical instead if the file might not exist.
  ```
- If you pass `VOLUME_NAME_NONE` to `GetFinalPathNameByHandle` it will strip that prefix *and* the drive letter, and it'll end up giving you a driveless path starting with `\`, which may or may not be useful depending on the situation, however...
- If you pass `VOLUME_NAME_NONE` but you also know that the file is on the same drive as the current working directory, both `std::filesystem` and [`GetFullPathName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfullpathnamea) can re-complete the path for you:

  ```
  ...
  // result will not include drive letter component
  GetFinalPathNameByHandle(hFile, existingTarget, MAX_PATH, 
                           FILE_NAME_OPENED | VOLUME_NAME_NONE);
  ...
  {
    // with std::filesystem into an std::string: 
    std::string cleanerPath = std::filesystem::absolute(existingTarget).string();
  }
  ...
  {
    // or with win api: 
    char cleanerPath[MAX_PATH];
    GetFullPathNameA(existingTarget, sizeof(cleanerPath), cleanerPath, nullptr);
  }
  ```
- You could also use [`GetFileInformationByHandleEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getfileinformationbyhandleex) instead of `GetFinalPathNameByHandle`, at the expense of a weirder API (and there's no ANSI version). *(todo: example; no more time right now)*

And, of course, you could leave the prefix, which *is* a valid path on Windows, even if it is a bit uncommon.

Answer (score -1):

Since Windows 8, you can simply call [PathCchStripPrefix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/pathcch/nf-pathcch-pathcchstripprefix) to remove the `\\?\` and the `\\?\UNC` prefix.