# Get real path from symlink C#

Tags: c#

Does anybody know how can get real path from symlink file or folder?

Comment: Please rewrite this as a question, and [put the solution as an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Thank you @Martheen, for this information!

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302416/in-net-how-to-obtain-the-target-of-a-symbolic-link-or-reparse-point

Answer (score 9):

After some research I found this solution for how to get real path of a Symlink. If you have a created symlink and want to check where is the real pointer of this file or folder. If someone have better way to write it please share.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateFileW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(string lpFileName, int dwDesiredAccess, int dwShareMode, IntPtr securityAttributes, int dwCreationDisposition, int dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetFinalPathNameByHandleW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int GetFinalPathNameByHandle([In] SafeFileHandle hFile, [Out] StringBuilder lpszFilePath, [In] int cchFilePath, [In] int dwFlags);

private const int CREATION_DISPOSITION_OPEN_EXISTING = 3;
private const int FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS = 0x02000000;

public static string GetRealPath(string path)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(path) && !File.Exists(path))
    {
        throw new IOException("Path not found");
    }

    SafeFileHandle directoryHandle = CreateFile(path, 0, 2, IntPtr.Zero, CREATION_DISPOSITION_OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, IntPtr.Zero); //Handle file / folder

    if (directoryHandle.IsInvalid)
    {
        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(512);
    int mResult = GetFinalPathNameByHandle(directoryHandle, result, result.Capacity, 0);

    if (mResult < 0)
    {
        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    }

    if (result.Length >= 4 && result[0] == '\\' && result[1] == '\\' && result[2] == '?' && result[3] == '\\')
    {
        return result.ToString().Substring(4); // "\\?\" remove
    }
    return result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Instead of doing `directoryHandle.DangerousGetHandle()` I think you can just change the signature to `private static extern int GetFinalPathNameByHandle([In] SafeFileHandle hFile, ...`