# How to check whether two file names point to the same physical file in C/C#/cmd on Windows?

Tags: c#, windows, cmd, symlink

Is there a simple way (like some low level Windows API) to know whether two absolute path of file names point to the same physical file on Windows in C# or C or cmd? Existing question seems to be about Unix and doesn't consider details bellow.

They may be:

(1) Real file

(2) Symbolic link

(3) Whose path contains some folder that is directory symbolic links (like created by mklink /d)

C# is best. If C then will Pinvoke it. If cmd then will Process.Start it.

Comment: Pick up a language, it does not make sense that a tagged question with C# accepts an answer in C as valid. 
There are ways (C#) to check if a file is a symbolic link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485155/check-if-a-file-is-real-or-a-symbolic-link

Comment: Does this do the trick? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067075/how-do-i-determine-a-mapped-drives-actual-path

Comment: You might want to compare file ID (like inode on Linux):  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162164/does-windows-have-inode-numbers-like-linux)

Comment: Found that this question works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38299901/get-real-path-from-symlink-c-sharp

Comment: @Alex Found that File ID works for directory symbolic links in the path, but doesn't work for file symbolic links, the file ids are different than the original file.