# How can I find the target of a Linux Symlink in C#

Tags: c#, linux, mono

In C#, I need to find the actual path of a file/directory in Linux that might be on the other side of a symlink.

I have found the solution to this on Windows at [How to obtain the target of a symbolic link (or Reparse Point) using .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2302416/608639), but that for fairly obvious reasons won't work on Linux. I could call out to readlink, but I may need to do this a lot, and I'd hate to spend all of that time handling external processes.

I'd like something like this:

```
string GetFinalPathName(string inputPath);
```

If the symlink is something like:

```
/link -> /actual/path
```

And I call `GetFinalPathName("/link/myfile.txt")` it should return "/actual/path/myfile.txt".

How can I find the target of a Linux Symlink in C#?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered a solution.

Start with the mono.posix-4.5 nuget package:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Posix-4.5/

Then the solution was simple:

```
return Mono.Unix.UnixPath.GetRealPath(path);
```

Comment: Bit more info about Mono.Posix:

[Mono.Posix.NETStandard](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Posix.NETStandard/) is more up-to-date and it supports .NET Standard.

Despite the Mono namespace, it does seem to be the Microsoft-endorsed way of making Posix/Unix calls. Details in [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/15289).

Answer (score 1):

While the [NuGet `Mono.Posix.NETStandard` library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Posix.NETStandard/) can do the job, use it with caution. To my mind, it produces unexpected, counterintuitive results. Below are some tests with output from `GetRealPath()` and similar functions on Max OSX Catalina (v.10.15.7).

Based on these tests, it looks like you cannot simply provide the full path to `GetRealPath()` or other functions and get the final target file path with symlinks resolved as a result. Instead, you need to test each folder in the path using `GetRealPath()` or `GetCompleteRealPath()`.

From the terminal:

```
$ pwd
/Volumes
$ ls -l 
total 0 
drwxr-xr-x  32 root    wheel  1156 Oct  7 17:12 HD2
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root    wheel     1 Nov 12 22:14 Mac HD -> /
```

From C# tests:

Input path: `/Volumes/Mac HD` <== **this is the root volume**

```
GetRealPath() => /
GetCompleteRealPath() => /
GetCanonicalPath() => /Volumes/Mac HD
```

Input path: `/Volumes/Mac HD/` <== **trailing slash produces unexpected results**

```
GetRealPath() => /Volumes/Mac HD/
GetCompleteRealPath() => /
GetCanonicalPath() => /Volumes/Mac HD
```

Input path: `/Volumes/Mac HD/Users/Shared/existing.txt` <== **existing file in symlinked volume results in "//" in `GetCompleteRealPath()`**

```
GetRealPath() => /Volumes/Mac HD/Users/Shared/existing.txt
GetCompleteRealPath() => //Users/Shared/existing.txt
GetCanonicalPath() => /Volumes/Mac HD/Users/Shared/existing.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have to create a native C/C++ project which exports a wrapper for the Linux readlink() function, and then use platform invoke to call it from C#. This appears to be how the CLR handles it.  Unfortunately, I don't think you can just call their implementation: [CLR Unix ReadLink code](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/Interop/Unix/System.Native/Interop.ReadLink.cs)