# How do I find the target of a Windows App Execution Alias in C#/Win32 api?

Tags: c#, alias, symlink

Microsft Windows Terminal (installed via the Microsoft Store) creates a 0 bytes `wt.exe` file which is a [Windows execution alias](https://www.tiraniddo.dev/2019/09/overview-of-windows-execution-aliases.html). AFAIK it is somthing similar to a symbolic link, except it seems to be resolved at the `CreateProcess` Api level as opposed to a symlink that is translated at the file system.

In powershell:

```bsh
❯ dir ~\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe

Mode    Name
----    ----
la---   wt.exe -> C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_1.0.1401.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\WindowsTerminal.exe

❯ Get-Item .\wt.exe | fl

Name           : wt.exe
Length         : 0
LinkType       : AppExeCLink
Target         : C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_1.0.1401.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\WindowsTerminal.exe
```

I wasn't able to find proper documentation for these "new" kind of aliases. Even googling PS `AppExeCLink` value is not very useful.

I need a fast way to resolve an execution alias (get the target file) in a C# App. Given my requirements, I prefer an unmanaged (Win32 Api) way over adding a reference to the slow WMI or an external 300kb nuget package.

Thanks!

Comment: This can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33487494/6208915

Comment: Thanks @Gabor. I tried it. It works with symbolic links, but not with this kind of aliases.

Comment: One baby step forward: [IO_REPARSE_TAG_APPEXECLINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-fscc/c8e77b37-3909-4fe6-a4ea-2b9d423b1ee4)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I faced the same problem in my [System Tools Library](https://github.com/JFLarvoire/SysToolsLib%22), which choked on these new type of links. This library is written in C, and uses the WIN32 API.

Here's what I found so far:

- Three years after their introduction in Windows, cmd.exe and PowerShell 5.1 are still unaware of App Exec Links, and report them as 0-byte files.

  But PowerShell Core 7 knows about them:

  ```
  PS C:\Temp> dir $env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\WindowsApps | ?{$_.LinkType} | select Name,LinkType,Target

  Name                        LinkType    Target
  ----                        --------    ------
  GameBarElevatedFT_Alias.exe AppExeCLink C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.XboxGamingOverlay_5.420.11102.0_x64__8w...
  MicrosoftEdge.exe           AppExeCLink C:\WINDOWS\system32\SystemUWPLauncher.exe
  python.exe                  AppExeCLink C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_1.11.3162.0_x64__8w...
  python3.exe                 AppExeCLink C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_1.11.3162.0_x64__8w...
  ubuntu.exe                  AppExeCLink C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_2004.2020.8...
  ubuntu1804.exe              AppExeCLink C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_2020.1...
  WinFR.exe                   AppExeCLink C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsFileRecovery_0.1.13492.0_x64__8w...
  winget.exe                  AppExeCLink C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_1.11.3162.0_x64__8w...
  wt.exe                      AppExeCLink C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_1.4.3243.0_x64__8wekyb3...

  PS C:\Temp>
  ```
- These App Exec Links are NTFS Reparse Points, tagged as
  IO_REPARSE_TAG_APPEXECLINK = 0x8000001b.

  You can read them in a C/C++/C# program using the WIN32 API  `DeviceIoControl()` with the `FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT` control code.

  My [readlink.c](https://github.com/JFLarvoire/SysToolsLib/blob/master/C/MsvcLibX/src/readlink.c) module contains a `ReadReparsePointW()` routine demonstrating this.
- You can dump the content of such a link, by running:

  ```
  fsutil reparsepoint query <REPARSE_POINT_PATHNAME>
  ```

  Ex:

  ```
  C:\Temp>fsutil reparsepoint query "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe"
  Reparse Tag Value : 0x8000001b
  Tag value: Microsoft

  Reparse Data Length: 0x168
  Reparse Data:
  0000:  03 00 00 00 4d 00 69 00  63 00 72 00 6f 00 73 00  ....M.i.c.r.o.s.
  0010:  6f 00 66 00 74 00 2e 00  57 00 69 00 6e 00 64 00  o.f.t...W.i.n.d.
  0020:  6f 00 77 00 73 00 54 00  65 00 72 00 6d 00 69 00  o.w.s.T.e.r.m.i.
  0030:  6e 00 61 00 6c 00 5f 00  38 00 77 00 65 00 6b 00  n.a.l._.8.w.e.k.
  0040:  79 00 62 00 33 00 64 00  38 00 62 00 62 00 77 00  y.b.3.d.8.b.b.w.
  0050:  65 00 00 00 4d 00 69 00  63 00 72 00 6f 00 73 00  e...M.i.c.r.o.s.
  0060:  6f 00 66 00 74 00 2e 00  57 00 69 00 6e 00 64 00  o.f.t...W.i.n.d.
  0070:  6f 00 77 00 73 00 54 00  65 00 72 00 6d 00 69 00  o.w.s.T.e.r.m.i.
  0080:  6e 00 61 00 6c 00 5f 00  38 00 77 00 65 00 6b 00  n.a.l._.8.w.e.k.
  0090:  79 00 62 00 33 00 64 00  38 00 62 00 62 00 77 00  y.b.3.d.8.b.b.w.
  00a0:  65 00 21 00 41 00 70 00  70 00 00 00 43 00 3a 00  e.!.A.p.p...C.:.
  00b0:  5c 00 50 00 72 00 6f 00  67 00 72 00 61 00 6d 00  \.P.r.o.g.r.a.m.
  00c0:  20 00 46 00 69 00 6c 00  65 00 73 00 5c 00 57 00   .F.i.l.e.s.\.W.
  00d0:  69 00 6e 00 64 00 6f 00  77 00 73 00 41 00 70 00  i.n.d.o.w.s.A.p.
  00e0:  70 00 73 00 5c 00 4d 00  69 00 63 00 72 00 6f 00  p.s.\.M.i.c.r.o.
  00f0:  73 00 6f 00 66 00 74 00  2e 00 57 00 69 00 6e 00  s.o.f.t...W.i.n.
  0100:  64 00 6f 00 77 00 73 00  54 00 65 00 72 00 6d 00  d.o.w.s.T.e.r.m.
  0110:  69 00 6e 00 61 00 6c 00  5f 00 31 00 2e 00 34 00  i.n.a.l._.1...4.
  0120:  2e 00 33 00 32 00 34 00  33 00 2e 00 30 00 5f 00  ..3.2.4.3...0._.
  0130:  78 00 36 00 34 00 5f 00  5f 00 38 00 77 00 65 00  x.6.4._._.8.w.e.
  0140:  6b 00 79 00 62 00 33 00  64 00 38 00 62 00 62 00  k.y.b.3.d.8.b.b.
  0150:  77 00 65 00 5c 00 77 00  74 00 2e 00 65 00 78 00  w.e.\.w.t...e.x.
  0160:  65 00 00 00 30 00 00 00                           e...0...

  C:\Temp>
  ```
- The reparse data there is a structure with four wide strings, looking like:

  ```
  typedef struct _REPARSE_APPEXECLINK_READ_BUFFER { // For tag IO_REPARSE_TAG_APPEXECLINK
    DWORD  ReparseTag;
    WORD   ReparseDataLength;
    WORD   Reserved;
    ULONG  Version;    // Currently version 3
    WCHAR  StringList[1];  // Multistring (Consecutive UTF-16 strings each ending with a NUL)
    /* There are normally 4 strings here. Ex:
      Package ID:  L"Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe"
      Entry Point: L"Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App"
      Executable:  L"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_1.4.3243.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\wt.exe"
      Applic. Type: L"0"   // Integer as ASCII. "0" = Desktop bridge application; Else sandboxed UWP application
    */     
  } APPEXECLINK_READ_BUFFER, *PAPPEXECLINK_READ_BUFFER;
  ```
- Running the App Exec Link target of wt.exe...

  ```
  "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_1.4.3243.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\wt.exe"
  ```

  ... works, and starts the Windows Terminal.

  But running the App Exec Link target of MicrosoftEdge.exe...

  ```
  "C:\WINDOWS\system32\SystemUWPLauncher.exe"
  ```

  ... does NOTHING.

  ⇒ The other parameters in the reparse data are somehow important. (But I don't know how to use them.)
- Running

  ```
  "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\MicrosoftEdge.exe"
  ```

  Then looking in Task Manager, I see that the real executable running for MS Edge is

  ```
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
  ```

  ⇒ This proves that the App Exec Link target program is not always the real program.
- It is possible to start the target application using the entry point string in the reparse data, instead of the target pathname, using:

  ```
  explorer.exe shell:appsFolder\<REPARSE_POINT_ENTRY_POINT_NAME>
  ```

  Ex, this starts Microsoft Edge:

  ```
  explorer.exe shell:appsFolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge
  ```

  But this is not what I want. I'd really want to find how to start the application using the target application pathname AND the other two parameters.

Anyway, I've updated the readlink() routine in my [MsvcLibX library](https://github.com/JFLarvoire/SysToolsLib/tree/master/C/MsvcLibX) to return the target of App Exec Links.
All the tools in my [System Tools Library](https://github.com/JFLarvoire/SysToolsLib%22) that can handle symbolic links now show that target.
But as this target is obviously not the complete answer, I consider this current version as a makeshift implementation at best.

If anybody finds more information on this subject, I'm very interested!

Comment: This is super helpfull! What I learned is that when you execute an AppExecLink, the CreateProcess function [behaves different](https://www.tiraniddo.dev/2019/09/overview-of-windows-execution-aliases.html), for example adding the `WIN:SYSAPPID` attribute to the security token. Hence, launching the link target directly will never get the same result. I've used `cmd /c wt.exe` as a workaround. I still have to re-read your info and find the best way to tell if it's an AppExecLink.

Comment: You also gave me the idea to check the Get-ChildItem implementation in PowerShell, found interesting WinInternalGetTarget and WinInternalGetLinkType functions in [FileSystemProvider.cs](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/v7.1.0/src/System.Management.Automation/namespaces/FileSystemProvider.cs#L8377)

Comment: Looking the PowerShell Core sources is indeed a good idea!  
Unrelated: I've corrected an error in my reply above: ReadReparsePointW() is an internal routine in my MsvcLibX library. The WIN32 API to use is DeviceIoControl().

Comment: The best way to tell if it's an AppExecLink is first to run `GetFileAttributesW()` to check if it's a reparse point; Then if it is, do a `DeviceIoControl(FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT)` to check if the reparse point tag is IO_REPARSE_TAG_APPEXECLINK.

Comment: Incidentally, Microsoft has [removed `AppExecLink` reparse point support](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/16044) from PowerShell as of a preview of 7.2.0.... They literally just ripped it out, with the output still showing that the files are links, with `name ->` but then just blank. I guess they didn't want people having this level of access to UWP/AppX magic, but it still sucks that PowerShell isn't immune to these politics.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try adding `Microsoft.PowerShell.5.1.ReferenceAssemblies` nuget package to your project.

Then the following code works:

```cs
using System.Linq;
using System.Management.Automation;

string wtPath =
    Path.Combine(
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),
        "Microsoft",
        "WindowsApps",
        "wt.exe"
    );

using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
    var psObject = ps.AddCommand("Get-Item").AddParameter("Path", wtPath).Invoke().Single();
    var psPropInfo = psObject.Properties["Target"];

    string[] targets = (psPropInfo.Value as List<string>).ToArray();

    Console.WriteLine($"[{psPropInfo.Name}]=[{String.Join("; ", targets)}]");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gabor. I think this will solve the problem for future visitors and deserves an upvote. But given that I need something faster than starting a PowerShell instance, I will not mark it as the accepted answer. Also, in a similar fashion, I could start a process `pwsh -NoProfile -c '(Get-Item wt.exe).Target'` and get the result.

Answer (score 1):

Thought I would also add [this related thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1437590/typing-python-on-windows-10-version-1903-command-prompt-opens-microsoft-stor/1652617#answer-1652617) on how this ReparsePoint link type is used by UWP exes and the WindowsApp store.

> **tl;dr;**
> The `~\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\` directory has EXEs
> that are using a special form of `IO_REPARSE_TAG_APPEXECLINK` ***symlink***
> to reference the actual UWP pkg located in
> `C:/Program Files/WindowsApps/`.